# How to incrementally add virtual devices?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a number of different tensorflow trained models in production. I only have 1 GPU and want to allocate only a portion of GPU memory for each model on demand. The problem is, I don't know exactly how many models are going to be used therefore cannot define all virtual devices together and tensorflow does not let me change virtual devices after it initialized them.

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(physical_devices[0],
                                           [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])

tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(physical_devices[0],
                                           [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024),
                                            tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])

# RuntimeError: Virtual devices cannot be modified after being initialized
```

Comment: You need to deploy each model in a separate process/subprocess and design some sort of IPC to start each model with the required amount of memory.

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal I have a single celery worker for this. Is there any way to handle it in a single process?

Comment: It's not possible if you want to assign fixed amounts of memory. If you're okay with letting models take as much memory as required, you can enable memory growth and let TF decide how much memory to assign to each model at runtime.